# In android Servic to track which application has focus

Tags: android, service

In android, is it possible to track which apk/ application is on the top/have focus.
This work to be done by a service. I don't have much knowledge regd this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActivityManager.getRunningTask`

`RunningTaskInfo.topActivity`

`ComponentName.getPackageName`

is that clear?